# What methods of the Long class generate exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

i've just started learning Java and i want to ask: What methods of the Long class generate exceptions (try-catch) and which situations lead to the following exceptions?

I found a manual, but it's difficult for me to find the right information
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Long.html

Please, i want to understand what methods of the Long class generate exceptions

Comment: In that very same page check in every method the section _**Throws**_ which indicates the exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the same page for the methods, mostly NumberFormatException if thrown by methods and by one constructor. And coming to your problem statement, try-catch is just one of the ways to catch exception other being the 'throws' keyword.

Comment: Is there an answer to the question:  which situations lead to the following exceptions?

Comment: @Glechik https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html read this